# Android Tutorial - HelloFormStuff - unable to resolve drawable error

Tags: android

I am going through the tutorial for HelloFormStuff located [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html):

I am stuck on the first mini-tutorial on this page which is simply adding a button that uses the images to the right as different states and when clicked it displays a toast message.

I am getting this error in the main.xml layout file:

> error! Unable to resolve drawable
>   "C:\Documents and Settings\Ray
>   James\workspace\HelloFormStuff\res\drawable\android_button.xml"
>   in attribute "background" Exception
>   details are logged in Window > Show
>   View > Error Log

I have the following images saved in the res/drawable folder:

android_normal.png
android_focused.png
android_pressed.png

Here is the code for the different states of the button that is saved in res/drawable/android_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/android_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/android_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/android_normal" />
</Selector>
```

Here is the code in main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/android_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for HelloFormStuff activity class:

```
package com.example.HelloFormStuff;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloFormStuff extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on clicks
                Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "Beep Bop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have no other errors showing up in eclipse.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Project Properties:
target: android 1.5 API 3
Editor: Eclipse Version: 3.6.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is because you capitalized "selector"?

Comment: Yes, thanks a bunch.  I feel like a dumb shit now but thanks for helping out.  It works now.  Thanks.

Comment: Nah, happens to everybody. The compiler ought to have told you, but since it didn't, you did the right thing asking for a second pair of eyes. :)